# How can I turn off Visual Studio 2010 script debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I don't really use the VS 2010 script debugging and would like to turn it off. I've tried running this registry command:

reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\AD7Metrics\Engine{F200A7E7-DEA5-11D0-B854-00A0244A1DE2} /v ProgramProvider /d {4FF9DEF4-8922-4D02-9379-3FFA64D1D639} /f

However, I get an error access denied error because while I am a local admin on my work PC I do not have the rights to run the reg add command. I can edit the registry though through regedit though for some reason.

I tried installing the Silverlight 2 toolkit as mentioned in this workaround:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/greggm/disabling-script-debugging-in-vs-2008-ie8)

However this does not work for me now that I have Silverlight 4 installed.

Disabling script debugging in Internet Explorer also does not fix the problem.

Is there any way to turn off the script documents degugging functionality either manually through regedit or via some other kind of workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem trying to resize iFrames across domains.  I ended up using  Firefox or Chrome instead of Internet Explorer, and that worked fine.  Would this work for your scenario with Silverlight?

Comment: Unfortunately, our app (which is a business Intranet app) is only "certified" against IE. So we have to run against it.

Comment: In that case, I'd say to run in release mode (Ctrl-F5), when testing this particular piece of functionality, and then make sure that your code is modular enough that you can debug the rest of your software without it.